# Negative Sentences

Tags: spoken-korean, negation

I want to know the difference between **지 않다** and the short form **안** to negate a sentence.

• Why **안** can only be used to selected verb/adjective? And what are those verbs/adjectives in general?

• Between the two, what native korean speaker typically uses to negate?

Comment: We have an answer to this question already on the site. However, that means that your question is a good one! Others also have wondered the same thing.